# Using nls in R, error message: Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Tags: r, statistics, nonlinear-functions

```
> lenss
    xd      yd      zd
1   0.0000  0.0000 2.44479
2   0.0937  0.0000 2.73183
3   0.3750  0.0000 2.97785
4   0.8437  0.0000 3.18626
5   1.5000  0.0000 3.36123
6   2.3437  0.0000 3.50624
7   3.3750  0.0000 3.62511
8   4.5937  0.0000 3.72124
9   5.9999  0.0000 3.79778
10  7.5936  0.0000 3.85744
11  9.3749  0.0000 3.90241
12 11.3436  0.0000 3.93590
13 13.4998  0.0000 3.96011
14 15.8435  0.0000 3.97648
15 18.3748  0.0000 3.98236
16 21.0935  0.0000 3.99406
17 23.9997  0.0000 3.99732
18 27.0934  0.0000 3.99911
19 30.3746  0.0000 4.00004
20 33.8433  0.0000 4.00005
21 37.4995  0.0000 4.00006
22  0.0663  0.0663 3.99973
23  0.2652  0.2652 3.99988
24  0.5966  0.5966 3.99931
25  1.0606  1.0606 3.99740
26  1.6573  1.6573 3.99375
27  2.3865  2.3865 3.98732
28  3.2482  3.2482 3.97640
29  4.2426  4.2426 3.95999
30  5.3695  5.3695 3.93598
31  6.6290  6.6290 3.90258
32  8.0211  8.0211 3.85171
33  9.5458  9.5458 3.79754
34 11.2031 11.2031 3.72156
35 12.9929 12.9929 3.62538
36 14.9153 14.9153 3.50636
37 16.9703 16.9703 3.36129
38 19.1579 19.1579 3.18622
39 21.4781 21.4781 2.97802
40 23.9308 23.9308 2.73206
41 26.5162 26.5162 2.44464
> rd=sqrt(xd^2+yd^2)
> fit=nls(zd~(rd^2/R)/(1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*rd^2/R^2))+d,start=list(R=75,k=-1,d=1))
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(1 - (1 + k) * rd^2/R^2) : NaNs produced
```

The function of that model was given above. The question states that there are a few inaccurate measurements in the data and I need to find them. I was going to fit the model first and work out every residuals in every measurement.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `sqrt` must be non-negative but there is no assurance that it is in the setup shown in the question.  Furthermore, even if that is fixed it seems unlikely that the model can be fit in the way shown in the question since it consists of two distinct curves (see graphic below) which likely will have to be separately fit.

Using the drc package we can get a reasonable fit using its `LL2.5` model like this:

```
library(drc)

plot(zd ~ rd)

g <- rep(1:2, c(21, 20))
fit1 <- drm(zd ~ rd, fct = LL2.5(), subset = g == 1)
fit2 <- drm(zd ~ rd, fct = LL2.5(), subset = g == 2)

lines(fitted(fit1) ~ rd[g == 1])
lines(fitted(fit2) ~ rd[g == 2])
```

This involves 10 parameters (5 for each curve).  You might try the different models available there by using different models for the `fct` argument to see if you can find somnething more parsimonious.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have one question. If the two different sets of data points are scramble (there are in order this case), is there a quick way to identify them?

Comment: It depends on how they are scrambled.  (1) If they are scrambled within group so that all of one group preceeds the other group then that would not change anything since `drm` does not depend on the order of the data.  (2) If the two groups are intermixed then you could try separating them by putting those with low zd/high rd and high zd/low rd in one group and those with low zd/low rd and high zd/low zd in another group and drop the intermediate points for whom its not clear which group they belong to.

Comment: The drc package is pretty new for me and it is very interesting. I am just wondering if you could use the model(function) that is given,(rd^2/R)/(1+sqrt(1-(1+k)*rd^2/R^2))+d. I found that very difficult to get nls woking because you have to get the initial value close enough to the actual value. The error message keep popping up.     Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Comment: For that use `nls`.  If we reparameterize so that .lin1 = 1/R .lin2 = d and exp(-b^2)/max(rd^2) = (1+k)/R^2 then this model seems to fit for the second group: `fit2 <- nls(zd~cbind(rd^2/(1+sqrt(1-exp(-b^2)/max(rd^2)*rd^2)), 1), start=list(b = 0), subset = g == 2, alg = "plinear")` but for the first group the attempts I made it did not give a reasonable fit so you will likely have to change your model for it.

Comment: Thank you. My lecture said I can change the model a bit.